# One relation not loading just after creation, but another one loads

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm encountering a weird problem in my Laravel 9 project.

I have this model `Team`, with a `logo` relation to another model `ImageVersion`, and a `city` relation to a `City` model, they're defined like this:

```php
public function city(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(City::class);
}

public function logo(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(ImageVersion::class, 'logo_image_version_id');
}
```

The problem is, when i'm creating a new `Team`, and setting both `city_id` and `logo_image_version_id`, only the city becomes available with `$team->city`, `$team->logo` stays `null`.

This is the code:

```php
public function update(Team $team, CreateOrUpdateTeamDto $dto): Team
{
    if ($team->logo && $team->logo->image_id !== $dto->logo_image_id) {
        $this->imageService->deleteVersion($team->logo);
    }

    $team->name = $dto->name;
    $team->manager = $dto->manager;
    $team->location = $dto->location;
    $team->city_id = $dto->city_id;

    if ($dto->logo_image_id) {
        $version = $this->imageService->createVersionIfDoesntExistFromId($dto->logo_image_id, 512, 512, keepWhenUnused: false);
        $team->logo_image_version_id = $version->id;
    }

    $team->save();

    return $team;
}

public function create(CreateOrUpdateTeamDto $dto): Team
{
    $team = new Team();
    return $this->update($team, $dto);
}
```

If I do a GET request on the `Team` I just created, I can access `logo` just fine, so there's probably no problems with the relation definition itself, the problem just happens in the request that creates it.

I know that I could probably just do a `$team->refresh()` before returning it, but I find it weird that it works just fine for `city`.

These are the queries logged by the request that creates the `Team`:

```sql
select * from `images_versions` where `image_id` = ? and `width` = ? and `height` = ? and `mime_type` = ? limit 1;  
select * from `images` where `images`.`id` in (5);  
insert into `teams` (`name`, `manager`, `location`, `city_id`, `logo_image_version_id`, `created_by_id`, `updated_by_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);  
select * from `cities` where `cities`.`id` = ? limit 1;  
select * from `states` where `states`.`id` in (6);
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to fix this is after `$team->logo_image_version_id = $version->id;` try adding `unset($team->logo);` to remove the null `$team->logo`

I believe when you are calling

```
$team->logo
```

in

```
if ($team->logo && $team->logo->image_id !== $dto->logo_image_id) {
   $this->imageService->deleteVersion($team->logo);
}
```

if the `$team` object does not yet have a `logo_image_version_id`, just calling `$team->logo` will set the `logo` property to null. Then after when you add the `logo_image_version_id` `$team->logo` is still `null`. And does not re query the DB

Comment: That does make sense, I'll try that as soon as I get home. For now, I fixed it using `$team->logo = $version;`, after the `->save()` which is probably even more efficient, since that it means that it doesn't get queried again